# Fourier transform of t*rect(t)

Tags: fourier-transform, fourier, fourier-series

In my previous post I asked for help for a Fourier transform of $$ t \text{rect} ( t- \frac{1}{2} ) $$ and I think I’ve understand the process. Now I’ve 2 another similar Fourier transform to do , I already solved both , but I don’t have the correct result. Can someone tell my if the 2 results I obtained are wrong ? Thank you

If $$ x(t) = t \text{rect}(t) $$ I obtained $$ X(f) = \frac {\text{sinc}(f) - \frac{1}{2} [e^{i \pi f } + e^{-i \pi f } ]}{i 2 \pi f } + \frac{1}{4} \delta(f) $$

And for $$ x(t) = \Big(t + \frac{1}{2}\Big) \text{rect}(t) $$ I obtained $$ X(f) = \frac{ \text{sinc}(f) - e^{- i \pi f } }{ i 2 \pi f } + \frac{1}{4} \delta (f) $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Derivative in frequency property of FT:

$$\frac{d}{d\omega}jF(\omega) \rightarrow tf(t)%$$

Time shift property of FT:

$$f(t-\tau) \rightarrow F(\omega)e^{-j\omega t_o}$$

FT of rect:  $F(\omega) = sinc(\omega/2)$

For practice if you are learning FT I recommend deriving the properties above to confirm you can get them from the FT directly using (practice makes perfect!):

$$F(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt$$

Comment: But with this I obtain that the Fourier transform of $$ t rect(t) $$ is $$ i \frac{d}{df} [sinc (f) ] $$ And that derivative of a sinc isn’t 0 ?

Comment: What makes you get 0?

Comment: I obtained 0 because I’m stupid :/ $$ sinc f = \frac{sen f }{f} $$ so I found that the derivative of this is $$ \frac{ [e^{ if } + e ^{ -if} ](if) - [ e^{if} - e ^{-if} ] }{2 i f^{2}} $$ now using the property should be $$ \frac{ [e^{ if } + e ^{ -if} ](if) - [ e^{if} - e ^{-if} ] }{2 f^{2}} $$

Comment: You're not stupid if you can figure all that out! Notice the cosine and sine equivalent in the expressions due to Euler's

Comment: @ElenaMartini See my update

Comment: Using Euler’s I obtain $$ \frac{ e^{if} + e^{-if} }{2i} - \frac{sen f}{f^{2}} $$’ and except for write the second part into a sinc, this is the last result I obtain. To obtain the first result I wrote :  I wrote x’(t) , I applied sampling properties and I made the Fourier transform to find $$ X_d f $$ and after I applied integration property to find tra final transformation ( as I it has been explained to me In the previous post but I’m sure I made some mistakes )